# Receiving donations by public Bitcoin wallet ID, where to make transparent deposits?

Tags: transactions, public-note

We are a **transparent [NGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-governmental_organization)**, so we not need secret transactions, we need to expose them...

We created a Bitcoin wallet to receive donator's deposits there (at `blockchain.info`), and now we have an **wallet ID**. Can we expose our wallet ID to the public? Donators can use the *wallet ID* to make donations, or we must to use address?

We need a *stable* and permanent ID/address to expose our transparent donation reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, do not expose your wallet ID. That is used for logging in to your wallet on the site and is for you only.

Instead, simply expose your bitcoin address. Making that publicly available will mean anyone can send your donations and everyone can see the transactions happening with that address. There is no security risk in exposing your bitcoin address to everyone, if you want transparency.